# Webcrawling: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

I need to take link to the latest user tiktok video. it worked, but then stopped working

```
import bs4
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.tiktok.com/@dava_m?"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36 OPR/81.0.4196.61'}
full_usd_page = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_usd_page, 'html.parser')
product_link = soup.find("a", class_="").get("href")
print(link)
```

```
product_link = soup.find("a", class_="").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

it returns none, but an hour ago it worked. pls help to get latest video link
https://www.tiktok.com/@dava_m?

Comment: How did it stop working? Does it print nothing? Does it crash? Does it print someting unexpected?

Comment: product_link = soup.find("a", class_="").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: forgot to write

Comment: Run `soup.find("a", class_="")` by itself. It is None, so you need to check this before calling `.get("href")`

Comment: but it just can t be none, im getting latest video, which definetely is not none in my tiktok example

Comment: You haven't provided a sample of how the HTML looks. Based on `soup.find("a", class_="")`, I think you might be looking for `soup.find("a", class_=False)`. `class=""` will look for elements with an empty class, `class_=False` will look for elements that do not have the class attribute

Comment: there s a class, but even if i add it it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This means soup.find("a", class_="") is returning a nonetype object. Try running it by itself without the get bit and check the output.
Make sure the output of the following is not None.

> soup.find("a", class_="")

It's possible that the function can't find anything.

Comment: The thing is it really returns None, but one hour ago it worked! IDK how. I can t understand which tag i should put.

Comment: https://www.tiktok.com/@dava_m? can you please make a code of getting the latest video link and compare it with mine, pls

Comment: You said it worked an hour ago - That's around the time that user "Dava_m" uploaded a new video. My guess is the upload of a new video changed the html code, meaning the find method no longer works. Use a debugger and check through the value of variable soup (the html).

Comment: I thought the same way, but since i turned my computer on, it made a new video link, and then just stopped working, idk how

Answer (score 0):

Probably the page is dynamically generated, and it's not sufficient to use simply `requests`. But other methods are quite more sophisticated. They might be `selenium`, `scrapy-splash`, etc. Search the web for `python scrape dynamic content/page`.